# Conditional Glyphicon using Jquery for Stock Price using Google Finance

Tags: jquery, stock

I am trying to get a stock quote working for a website.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a glyphicon displayed at "StockDirectionValue" instead of stockInfo.cp value.

The glyphicon needs to be conditional... depending on the output of StockInfo.cp which could be positive, negative or static.

This is the jquery code I'm using and this is working fine.

```
var gstock = ["NASDAQ:AAPL", "PPY:000001"];
for (var i = 0; i < gstock.length; i++) {
    $.getJSON("https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q="+gstock[i]+"&callback=?", function (response) {
        var stockInfo = response[0];
        var stockString = '<div class="stockWrapper">Nasdaq:';
        stockString += '<span class="stockDirectionValue">' + stockInfo.cp + '</span>';
        stockString += '<span class="stockPrice">' + stockInfo.l + '</span>';
        stockString += '<span class="stockChange">' + stockInfo.c + '</span>';
        stockString += '</div>';
        $('.stockNasdaq').prepend(stockString);
    });
}
```

The HTML is pretty simple.

```
<div class="stockNasdaq"></div>
```

Can someone help!

Comment: where should the glyphicon to appear?

Comment: Before the Stock Price... actually even if it is before the Nasdaq it should be okay...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getGlyph(cp) {
        var glyphicon = '';
        if (cp < 0) {
            glyphicon = ' glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down';
        }else if (cp >= 0) {
            glyphicon = ' glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up';
        }
        return glyphicon;
    }
    var gstock = ["NASDAQ:AAPL", "PPY:000001"];
    for (var i = 0; i < gstock.length; i++) {
        $.getJSON("https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=" + gstock[i] + "&callback=?", function (response) {
            var stockInfo = response[0];
            var stockString = '<div class="stockWrapper">Nasdaq: ';
            stockString += '<span class="stockDirectionValue' + getGlyph(stockInfo.cp) + '"> ' + stockInfo.cp + '</span>';
            stockString += '<span class="stockPrice">' + stockInfo.l + '</span>';
            stockString += '<span class="stockChange">' + stockInfo.c + '</span>';
            stockString += '</div>';
            $('.stockNasdaq').prepend(stockString);
        });
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="stockNasdaq"></div>
```

Comment: I edited the code a bit by adding another if else statement for cp==0 (right arrow glyphicon). Colored them using css and its looking slick :) Thanks for your help...

Comment: glad i could help.